# How can I use white space as a grouping separator in DecimalFormat?

Tags: java, google-visualization, decimalformat

I working on a Google Chart. The API uses the `DecimalFormat (ICU4J 53.1)`. I am aiming this format:

```
### ### meters
```

But I can't find it inside the [documentation](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html). Is there a work around for it?

Comment: Do you mean using space as a thousands separator?

Comment: Yes, exactly, like here: 100 000 meters.

Comment: The Visualization API does not expose any means of specifying the grouping symbol in the axis formatting; it is determined by the browser's locale.  You can around the limitations in the format by specifying the `hAxis.ticks` option, which creates custom labels: `hAxis: {ticks: [{v: 1000, f: '1 000'}, {v: 2000, f: '2 000'}, {v: 3000, f: '3 000'} ...]}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the `DecimalFormat` object, you can adjust it as follows:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbols = format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
formatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(formatSymbols);
```

If you only have access to the format string, then you cannot achieve your goal. The `DecimalFormat` class formats numbers according to the locale and the grouping separator is taken from that.

Comment: Thank you!

Would you explain that to use it inside the Google API function?

`vAxis: {
               gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},
               textStyle: {fontSize:'16'},
               format:'###### Meter' 
                }`